# Is there a way to convert user id to their username before embedding?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

so I have a notepad that saves the user id of any user on a particular server. Is there a way to display the username using the user id when embedding?

The notepad looks something like this:

```
<@xxxxxxxxxxx>=1.62
<@xxxxxxxxxxx>=1.31
```

I have tried almost everything. I need help.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def trial(ctx):
   embed = discord.Embed(title="Hello",color=0x00FFFF)
   f=open("KD.txt","r")
   x=1
   for line in f:
       y=''
       user,CMMR=line.split("=")
       y=(str(x)+". "+user)
       embed.add_field(name=y,value=CMMR,inline=False)
       x+=1
   await bot.say(embed=embed)
   f.close()
```

I expect the username to be displayed. My results are its just displays the user id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Server.get_member()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Server.get_member) method to do something like

`y=(str(x)+". "+ctx.message.server.get_member(user[2:-1]).display_name)`

Comment: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'display_name' i get this error ://

Comment: The `get_member` method returned NoneType meaning it couldn't find the member with that id. I've updated the code to extract the id from the `<@xxx>` format to `xxx` format, does that work?

Comment: If you've tried it with `ctx.message.server.get_member(user[2:-1]).display_name)` try removing the brackets and see if that works `ctx.message.server.get_member(user).display_name)`

Comment: No problem, to mark to anyone in the future reading this with a similar problem you can mark the thread as 'answered' by [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)